# Handle Click Outside of Render()

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core

I'm new to React and am trying to figure out the proper way to handle an event handler outside the Return() of a component. If this isn't the correct way to do things, I am open to a 'better' solution that follows convention.

The component's Render has this:

```
public render() {
    type CostMap_Import = typeof CostMap_Import;
    type SchedMap_Import = typeof SchedMap_Import;
    let importFields = this.props.selected == rdEV ? CostMap_Import : SchedMap_Import;

    let fields = Object.keys(importFields).map((i: Key) => {
        return <Dropdown menuItems={this.state.items} menuTitle={i} onSelect={this.handleFieldSelect}/>
    })

    let fieldCount = fields.length
    let contents = this.state.loading
        ? <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
        : Upload_FieldMapping.renderFieldMapGrid(fieldCount, fields)

    return <div>{contents}</div>
}
```

Where Upload_FieldMapping.renderFieldMapGrid is:

```
private static renderFieldMapGrid(count: number, fields: any) {
    const centerLabel: any = { display: 'block', textAlign: 'center', lineHeight: '100%', fontSize: '2em', marginLeft: '100px' }
    let topHalf = fields.slice(0, count / 2)
    let bottomHalf = fields.slice(count / 2)
    return <Grid>
        <Row>
            <label style={centerLabel}>SELECT FIELD MAPPING BELOW:</label>
        </Row>
        <br/>
        <Row className="show-grid row">
            <Col sm={4} smPush={4}>
                {topHalf}
            </Col>
            <Col sm={4} smPush={4}>
                {bottomHalf}
            </Col>
        </Row>
        <br />
        <Row style={centerDiv}>
            <input type="submit" value="Next" className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.handleMappingSubmit}/> 
        </Row>
    </Grid>
}
```

This is following a similar pattern in the Asp.NET Core 2.0 React app template.

The error I'm receiving:

```
"TS2339 (TS) Property 'handleMappingSubmit' does not exist on type 'typeof Upload_FieldMapping'."
```

at:

```
<input type="submit" value="Next" className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.handleMappingSubmit}/>
```

**EDIT**
The constructor:

```
constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { items: [], loading: true };
    this.onFieldSelect = this.onFieldSelect.bind(this)
    this.handleMappingSubmit = this.handleMappingSubmit.bind(this)

}
```

**SOLUTION**

As mentioned in the selected solution, the answer was to make renderFieldMapGrid an instance method by removing `static` and changing `Upload_FieldMapping.renderFieldMapGrid(fieldCount, fields)` to `this.renderFieldMapGrid(fieldCount, fields)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `renderFieldMapGrid` is a static method, so `this` in the `onClick` handler refers to the class `Upload_FieldMapping` itself rather than an instance. This is why the TypeScript error mentions `typeof Upload_FieldMapping` instead of `Upload_FieldMapping`.

To fix it, you could pass the instance as an extra argument to `renderFieldMapGrid`, but it probably makes more sense to just turn it into an instance method by removing `static` and invoking it on `this` instead of `Upload_FieldMapping`.

Answer (score 0):

From the React [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html):

> You have to be careful about the meaning of `this` in JSX callbacks. In JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default. If you forget to bind `this.handleClick` and pass it to `onClick`, `this` will be undefined when the function is actually called.
>
> This is not React-specific behavior; it is a part of how functions work in JavaScript. Generally, if you refer to a method without () after it, such as onClick={this.handleClick}, you should bind that method.

---

Assuming `this.handleMappingSubmit` is a function within the Component. 
 In your constructor function simply add this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.handleMappingSubmit = this.handleMappingSubmit.bind(this);
}
```

If the function is in a different file.  You bind it like this:

```
import { handleMappingSubmit } from './path/more-path';

// ...

constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.handleMappingSubmit = handleMappingSubmit.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response. Should have added this before - the binding is already a part of the component. See my edit.